# How can I create a partial (hybrid) mock in googlemock?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googlemock

Google suggests [delegating calls to a parent object](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#delegating-calls-to-a-real-object) when you need to invoke functionality of the real object, however this does not really create a partial (hybrid) mock. When invoking the real object, any method calls are those of the real object and not the mock object, on which you may have set up actions/expectations. How do I create a partial mock that delegates only specific methods to the real object, and all other method calls to the mock object?

#### Delegate to real object example

```
using ::testing::_;
using ::testing::AtLeast;
using ::testing::Invoke;

class MockFoo : public Foo {
 public:
  MockFoo() {
    // By default, all calls are delegated to the real object.
    ON_CALL(*this, DoThis())
        .WillByDefault(Invoke(&real_, &Foo::DoThis));
    ON_CALL(*this, DoThat(_))
        .WillByDefault(Invoke(&real_, &Foo::DoThat));
    ...
  }
  MOCK_METHOD0(DoThis, ...);
  MOCK_METHOD1(DoThat, ...);
  ...
 private:
  Foo real_;
};
...

  MockFoo mock;

  EXPECT_CALL(mock, DoThis())
      .Times(3);
  EXPECT_CALL(mock, DoThat("Hi"))
      .Times(AtLeast(1));
  ... use mock in test ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of creating an instance of the real object as a member variable, the mock should simply extend the real object, then delegate all calls to the parent by default. You can now setup your mock like normal; setting a new `ON_CALL` will override the default call to the parent. We let polymorphism do the work for us -- all calls, even from the parent (real) object, invoke the mock object, then the `ON_CALL` statement was set to invoke either the parent object or the mock behavior. We have successfully mixed real object behavior with mock behavior. This is exactly the same as [delegating calls to a parent class](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Delegating_Calls_to_a_Parent_Class).

#### Delegate to parent class example

```
class Foo {
 public:
  virtual ~Foo();

  virtual void Pure(int n) = 0;
  virtual int Concrete(const char* str) { ... }
};

class MockFoo : public Foo {
 public:
  // Mocking a pure method.
  MOCK_METHOD1(Pure, void(int n));
  // Mocking a concrete method.  Foo::Concrete() is shadowed.
  MOCK_METHOD1(Concrete, int(const char* str));

  // Use this to call Concrete() defined in Foo.
  int FooConcrete(const char* str) { return Foo::Concrete(str); }
};

using ::testing::Invoke;
// Create mock instance foo.
...
// Delegate to parent.
ON_CALL(foo, Concrete(_))
    .WillByDefault(Invoke(&foo, &MockFoo::FooConcrete));
```

The only downside to this technique is that it requires a lot of boilerplate code and is sensitive to code changes. I have extended googlemock to ease this process; the code is [available here](https://github.com/ericsubach/googlemock). It will generate partial mocks that call the parent (real) object by default for all methods, and generate matching constructors that pass arguments to the parent constructor.

Comment: Is this still the only way? It's so annoying to have to mention all methods.

Comment: I have not investigated this in years. Perhaps they updated it or maybe there are other frameworks where it is easier. It looks like Google Mock is now part of [Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest). If necessary, you can port my tool into the new framework -- it really did save a lot of typing.

Answer (score 2):

The official [Google Mock guideline](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#delegating-calls-to-a-real-object) and also the last proposal do work however introduce a lot of boilerplate code.

So here is my proposal:

`Foo.h`

```
class Foo {
 public:
  virtual ~Foo();

  virtual void Pure(int n) = 0;
  virtual int Concrete(const char* str) { ... }
};
```

`MockFoo.h`

```
class MockFoo: public Foo {
 using Real = Foo;
 public:
  MockFoo();
  virtual ~MockFoo();

  MOCK_METHOD1(Pure, void(int n));
  MOCK_METHOD1(Concrete, int(const char* str));
};
```

`MockFoo.cpp`

```
MockFoo::MockFoo() {
 using ::testing::Invoke;
 ON_CALL(*this, Pure()).WillByDefault(Invoke([this] {return Real::Pure();}));
 ON_CALL(*this, Concrete()).WillByDefault(Invoke([this] {return Real::Concrete();}));
};

MockFoo::~MockFoo() = default;
```

It's worth noting that having an implementation file for the mock is a good practice with observable benefits for test compilation time. Nice and easy.

Comment: Google Mock guideline link is broken. New link: [Google mock guideline](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#delegating-calls-to-a-real-object)

Comment: Thanks @reesjones, it’s fixed now.